# ¿Como puedo resolver este programa? Java Ciclo For

Tags: java, if, bucle-for

Se requiere desarrollar un programa que permita administrar la información para organizar la quinta edición de una maratón .
Se sabe que:

1. Por temas de organización, se admite una cantidad máxima de 15.000 (pero le puse 5 en el programa para poder verificar que me den bien lo que me pide) participantes.
2. Las distancias de la carrera son (en km):

   1. 10
   2. 5
   3. 2
3. Los talles de las remeras pueden ser:

   1. ‘S’
   2. ‘M’
   3. ‘L’
4. Se ofrecerá:

   1. 1 botella de agua por cada corredor de los 10K
   2. 0.5 botella de agua por cada corredor de los 5K
   3. 1 botella de agua cada 4 corredores de los 2K

Se desea:

1. Poder ingresar los 15.000 participantes
2. Tomar los siguientes datos:

   1. Edad
   2. Distancia que corre
   3. Talle remera
3. Calcular:

   1. Edad promedio de los participantes
   2. Cantidad de corredores por distancia
   3. Cantidad de remeras por talle que se deben comprar(Este punto no me estaría saliendo y no se como hacerlo.)
   4. Cantidad botellas de agua que se deben comprar

Mi código hasta ahora es este:

```
    int participantes = 5;
    int km = 0;
    int km10 = 0;
    int km5 = 0;
    int km2 = 0;
    String talles = " ";
    int talleS = 0;
    int talleM = 0;
    int talleL = 0;
    int botella = 0;
    int edad;
    int edadPromedio;
    int sumatoriaEdad = 0;

    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 1; i < participantes; i++) {

        System.out.println(i + ".Ingrese la edad : ");
        edad = teclado.nextInt();
        edad++;
        System.out.println(i + ".Ingrese la distancia que recorre : ");
        km = teclado.nextInt();
        System.out.println(i + ".Ingrese talle : ");
        talles = teclado.next();

        switch (km) {

        case 10:

            if (km == 10) {

                System.out.println("Se ofrece 1 botella de agua.");

                km10++;
                botella++;

            }

            break;

        case 5:

            if (km == 5) {

                System.out.println("Se ofrece 0.5 botella de agua.");

                km5++;
                botella++;

            }

            break;

        case 2:

            if (km == 2) {

                if ((i % 4) == 0) {

                    System.out.println("Se ofrece 1 botella de agua cada cautro corredores.");

                    botella++;
                }

                km2++;

            }

            break;

        default:

            System.out.println("Error! Distancia inexistente");

            break;

        }

        switch (talles) {

        case "S":

            if (talles == "S") {

                if (i == 1) {

                    talleS++;

                }

            }

            break;

        case "M":

            if (talles == "M") {

                if (i == 1) {

                    talleM++;

                }

            }

            break;

        case "L":

            if (talles == "L") {

                if (i == 1) {

                    talleL++;

                }

            }

            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("Error! talle inesxistente.");

            break;

        }

        sumatoriaEdad += edad;

    }

    edadPromedio = sumatoriaEdad / 5;

    System.out.println("Edad promedio : " + edadPromedio);

    System.out.println("Cantidad de corredores por distancia : ");
    System.out.println("Corredores de km 10 : " + km10);
    System.out.println("Corredores de km 5 : " + km5);
    System.out.println("Corredores de km 2 : " + km2);

    System.out.println("Cantidad de remeras por talle que se deben comprar  : ");
    System.out.println("Talle S : " + talleS);
    System.out.println("Talle M : " + talleM);
    System.out.println("Talle L : " + talleL);

    System.out.println("Cantidad de botellas de agua que se deben comprar : " + botella);
```

Comment: Podes aclarar donde especificamente tenes el problema, que resultado esperas, cual obtenes y que falla?

Comment: Si , ahi lo actualice , es el punto 3)c) que no me esta saliendo : "Cantidad de remeras por talle que se deben comprar"

Comment: Los talles al ser un String no se como calcular la cantidad que se van ingresando.

Comment: El primer problema que veo, es que no entendes como funciona un switch, que es basicamente un if..else, con varios else. volver a usar un if dentro del switch no tiene sentido. Despues, el switch deberia funcionar sobre el string de talle igual que con numeros. Probaste hacer un debug de tu aplicacion y ver que pasa? ojo que el switch es sensitivo a mayusculas y minusculas

Comment: La pregunta no es amplia, creo que está más que clara.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema está acá:

```
if (i == 1) {

    talleS++;

}
```

Te explico, tú estás recorriendo desde 1 hasta la cantidad de participantes, que por cierto, debería ser hasta participantes+1 el bucle for porque sino, al quitar el participante "0" como que la cantidad total de participantes será siempre menos 1.
No sé bien qué quisiste poner o por qué pusiste ese if, pero viendo tú código, sólo se va a ejecutar una vez! Por lo que talleS, talleL y talleM siempre van a valer 1 por más que pongas un millón de participantes.

Cuando pases a ingresar los datos del participante número 2, ya no te va a sumar ninguno de los talles puesto que i==2 y no a 1 como pusiste en el if.

Sugerencia:

Como talles es una cadena y tú lo que haces es ingresar M, L o S, entonces, en la posición "0" de la cadena va a estar una letra y si esa letra concuerda con M, L o S, entonces se tiene que incrementar la variable talleS, talleL o talleM respectivamente.
Además, concuerdo con lo que dijo **gbianchi**, si pones: case 10, ya estás haciendo if(km==10), es innecesario y poco práctico ponerlo nuevamente.

Espero sea ese el problema! Este sería el código que yo pondría:

```
int participantes = 5;
int km = 0;
int km10 = 0;
int km5 = 0;
int km2 = 0;
String talles = " ";
int talleS = 0;
int talleM = 0;
int talleL = 0;
int botella = 0;
int edad;
int edadPromedio;
int sumatoriaEdad = 0;
Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
for (int i = 1; i < (participantes+1); i++) {
    System.out.println(i + ".Ingrese la edad : ");
    edad = teclado.nextInt();
    edad++;
    System.out.println(i + ".Ingrese la distancia que recorre : ");
    km = teclado.nextInt();
    System.out.println(i + ".Ingrese talle : ");
    talles = teclado.next();
    switch (km) {
        case 10:
            System.out.println("Se ofrece 1 botella de agua.");
            km10++;
            botella++;
            break;
        case 5:
            System.out.println("Se ofrece 0.5 botella de agua.");
            km5++;
            botella++;
            break;
        case 2:
            if ((i % 4) == 0) {
                System.out.println("Se ofrece 1 botella de agua cada cautro corredores.");
                botella++;
            }
            km2++;
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Error! Distancia inexistente");
            break;
    }
    switch (talles[0]) {
        case 'S':
            talleS++;
            break;
        case 'M':
            talleM++;
            break;
        case 'L':
            talleL++;
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Error! talle inexistente.");
            break;
    }
    sumatoriaEdad += edad;
}
edadPromedio = sumatoriaEdad / 5;
System.out.println("Edad promedio : " + edadPromedio);
System.out.println("Cantidad de corredores por distancia : ");
System.out.println("Corredores de km 10 : " + km10);
System.out.println("Corredores de km 5 : " + km5);
System.out.println("Corredores de km 2 : " + km2);
System.out.println("Cantidad de remeras por talle que se deben comprar  : ");
System.out.println("Talle S : " + talleS);
System.out.println("Talle M : " + talleM);
System.out.println("Talle L : " + talleL);
System.out.println("Cantidad de botellas de agua que se deben comprar : " + botella);
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias , ya lo pude solucionar :D , voy a tener en cuenta lo que me explicaste , soy nuevo en esto y la verdad es que me cuesta un poco entenderlo :/  , Saludos !

Comment: Como sugerencia para mejorar el código, si ocurre algún error del tipo talle inexistente o distancia inexistente, tendrías que restarle lo que sumaste a km10, km5 o km2, o, a talleS, talleL, talleM. Además, tendrías que poner que si km no es 10, 5 o 2, no entre en el switch de talles(? y por último, al contador i, tendrías que restarle 1, ya que el corredor tiene que volver a registrarse nuevamente.